# android studio intentservice not running outside of application

Tags: java, android, intentservice

I'm trying to have an intentservice working like I did with a location service saving within a file perfectly.

The service pops up a notification when a file occurs in a directory.
this works nicely inside an activity but doesn't when I close.

Here is my code :

```
public class NotifyService extends IntentService {



public NotifyService() {
    super("NotifyService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
          File alerte = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
            File.separator +"SmartCollecte"+File.separator+ "ALERTE"+File.separator+ "IN"+File.separator+"alerte");
    if(alerte.exists()){
        createNotification();
    }
    else{}

}




@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public void createNotification() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);


    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("nouvelle collecte " + "test@gmail.com")
            .setContentText("une nouvelle collecte est disponible").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
            .build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

}
```

}

I can't just find what I'm missing...
Thanks for your help

Comment: what version of android you test on

Comment: I'm still on 5.1 by now

Comment: how do you fire the intent service?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241302/intentservice-will-be-killed-after-i-stop-my-application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntentService will be killed after I stop my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241302/intentservice-will-be-killed-after-i-stop-my-application)

Comment: well by adding setIntentRedelivery(true); doesn't change nothing at all @Vyacheslav I'm firing the intentservice with : startService(new Intent(this,NotifyService.class));

Answer (score 0):

This solution works only for preor 26 (Android O) SDK:

You have to launch your intent service using `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`
Using this way you can manage your service using alarmmanager, you prevent from being killed by system (wake lock) and remove `Activity` dependecies.

Futhermore, I'd suggest to use this same in order to implement you idea.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: this seems to be the right way to do what I want! Thanks Vyacheslav I found a good example to use the alarmmanager : https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/1627/alarmmanager-with-broadcastreceiver-in-android