# registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener not working for changes made in different process

Tags: android, process, sharedpreferences

I have registered `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` with my `SharedPreferences` in my Activity. When I change the data saved with `SharedPreferences` inside service running in different process, `onSharedPreferenceChanged` is not called!

What should I do to make android call `onSharedPreferenceChanged`?

Comment: Need more info...

Also check this
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799038/onsharedpreferencechanged-not-fired-if-change-occurs-in-separate-activity][1]

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542938/sharedpreferences-onsharedpreferencechangelistener-not-being-called-consistently/3104265#3104265][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799038/onsharedpreferencechanged-not-fired-if-change-occurs-in-separate-activity
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542938/sharedpreferences-onsharedpreferencechangelistener-not-being-called-consistently/3104265#3104265

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Most likely, it is being garbage collected by gc. I have faced this problem before. Make a global variable which keeps a hard reference to the listener.

```
  OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
      public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
        // Implementation
      }
    };
```

The answer at [SharedPreferences.onSharedPreferenceChangeListener not being called consistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542938/sharedpreferences-onsharedpreferencechangelistener-not-being-called-consistently/3104265#3104265) explains it best

Comment: I tried doing this...but still not working! As I change my service to run in the same process everything works fine.....I guess onChangeListener is not able to detect the changes made by other process....

Comment: this listener would be part of the process in which it was created as it would be made in its context. you may have to implement another listener in other process.

Comment: After implementing the listener in other process how will I refresh the current view. I mean Interaction of my current activity from the onChangeListener in some other process?

Comment: make a broadcast receiver and register it with your custom action. When work is done from one process, broadcast the string. On receiving broadcast update your activity.