# Getting a classcastexception when trying a custom marker in google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to create a custom marker in google maps.I want to add a custom layout as the marker

So i used the following code inside a webservice:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        View custom_layout = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_marker_layout,null);
        ImageView iv_category_logo=(ImageView) custom_layout.findViewById(R.id.iv_category_logo);
        pinbit=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(pinbit,75,56,false);
        iv_category_logo.setImageBitmap(pinbit);
        //pinbit=MainActivity.getCroppedBitmap(pinbit, 10);
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(getApplicationContext(), custom_layout)));
      // adding marker


      googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    }

public static Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Context context, View view) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
```

But a classcastexception is shown in the following line:

```
((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
```

The logcat is shown below:

```
07-18 16:08:07.617: E/AndroidRuntime(22114): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 16:08:07.617: E/AndroidRuntime(22114): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
07-18 16:08:07.617: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at com.igloo.storelocater.MainActivity.createDrawableFromView(MainActivity.java:610)
07-18 16:08:07.617: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at com.igloo.storelocater.MainActivity$retrieveimage.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:600)
07-18 16:08:07.617: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at com.igloo.storelocater.MainActivity$retrieveimage.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
07-18 16:08:07.617: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
07-18 16:08:07.617: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
07-18 16:08:07.617: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
07-18 16:08:07.617: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 16:08:07.617: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-18 16:08:07.617: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3689)
07-18 16:08:07.617: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 16:08:07.617: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-18 16:08:07.617: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
07-18 16:08:07.617: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-18 16:08:07.617: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

}

please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in using of getApplicationContext() method. It is strongly recommended to avoid using it when you're working with some screen local stuff. See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()) for this method. It does not return an Activity object. I would suggest you to use inter-process communication (IPC) to pass data between your Service and Activity. One possible way is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20595215/1320299). For another ways you can read [Developers page](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#IPC).