# IntentService finish parent Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

I am using an Activity called "FirstStart" in my Android Application. After the user press a "register" Button, I start a registration intent service to register the user on my server and on GCM.
In my `onClik(View v)` I start the Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
        intent.putExtra("user", givenUsername);
        startService(intent);
```

After this, the `public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)` starts and get a token from GCM and put this to my server.

This process needs a few seconds. I dont want the user to wait on the normal screen, so I put a progress bar in the FirstStart Activity. It is called and started before the RegistrationIntentService starts.

After the registration intent service finished, I want to stop the progress bar in FirstStart and finish the registration intent service and also the FirstStart Activity.

So how can I finish the FirstStart Activity at the end of my RegistrationIntentService?
Or is there a way to go back into the FirstStart Activity, when the RegistrationIntentService is finished?

Comment: please Google ResultReceiver class

Comment: It sounds like the best option for you is to bind the Service to your Activity.  Take a look at this example, see that it calls `bindService()`, and look at the `Callbacks` interface in the service, and the `updateClient()` implementation in the Activity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594936/communication-between-activity-and-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how can I finish the FirstStart Activity at the end of my
>   RegistrationIntentService?

Obviously a communication between FirstStart and the RegistrationIntentService must be established. The fastest way to achieve it would be to:

- register [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) in the `FirstStart` by using `registerReceiver()` method. Secondly, once all the job within the `RegistrationIntentService` is done, the only thing you have to do is to `sendBroadcast()` from the Service. Remember about the `IntentFilter` with proper action set so that the broadcast sent from the `RegistrationIntentService` will match registered `BroadcastReceiver` in `FirstStart`
- Do basically the same thing as in the first suggestion but by using `LocalBroadcastManager` The distinction between regular broadcasting and broadcasting with the `LocalBroadcastManager` is that in the latter case broadcast messages are visible only for your application's process. In the former one, the Broadcast may be intercepted by different application (if no permission is restricted ofc)
- Use some open-source goods like green robot's [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) which does basically technically the same thing in terms of broadcasting but with custom Objects you create.

> Or is there a way to go back into the FirstStart Activity, when the
>   RegistrationIntentService is finished?

Still, broadcast-based communication is the way you make the Activity speak with Service.

Hope that helps somehow:)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The LocalBroadcastManager solves my communication problem. I also found this nice example code for a LocalBroadcastManager: https://gist.github.com/Antarix/8131277