# Add item to RecyclerView via Service Class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-service

In my `Fragment` class, this is how I add an Item to my `RecyclerView`.

```
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.online_devices, container, false);

            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getBaseContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            theDataList = new ArrayList<>();
            theRecyclerAdpater = new TheRecyclerAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), theDataList);

            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(theRecyclerAdpater);

            TheData a = new TheData("01","another value","another value","another value","another value");
                        theDataList.add(a);
                    a = new TheData("02","another value","another value","another value","another value");
                        theDataList.add(a);
            theRecyclerAdpater.notifyDataSetChanged();

            return view;
        }
```

But what if I want to add an Item to my `RecyclerView` via `Service` when the `UI` is Available? I mean, The `Service` is running in background and if the `Main UI` of application where the `RecyclerView` is `Available` then Add an Item Otherwise don't Add an Item. Anyone has an idea on how can i possible do that?

For now, I only have this in my `Service`

```
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        //Add an Item here to RecyclerView if the UI is Available.
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

**UPDATE**
I just try this but not working.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.online_devices, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        theDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        theRecyclerAdpater = new TheRecyclerAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), theDataList);

        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(theRecyclerAdpater);

        getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(),MyService.class));
        bus.register(this);

        return view;
     }

            @Subscribe
            public void getMessage(String s) {
               TheData a = new TheData(s);
               theDataList.add(a);
               theRecyclerAdpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
```

in my Service

```
@Override
public void onCreate(){
     bus.post("PP");
}
```

Comment: use `LocalBroadcastReceiver`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communication between Activity and Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594936/communication-between-activity-and-service)

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, `Otto` is now depreciated, I had to change it to [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). I had to ask it again, Thank to [you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38121081/using-otto-in-fragment-and-service-class/38122248#38122248). So this is what I did.

added to gradle `compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'`

In my Fragment Class

```
/*I had to import*/
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode;


public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    static TheRecyclerAdapter theRecyclerAdpater;
    private List<TheData> theDataList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this); //Register it first

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.online_devices, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        theDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        theRecyclerAdpater = new TheRecyclerAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), theDataList);

        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(theRecyclerAdpater);

        getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(),MyService.class)); //I call the Service

        return view;
    }

    //Subscribe, run it on UI
    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onEvent(TheData data){
        TheData a = new TheData(data.getPc_number());
        theDataList.add(a);
        theRecyclerAdpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

and in my Service class

```
public class ServerHelperService extends Service {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
       EventBus.getDefault().post(new TheData("OK")); //and This
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

and it's done. Still reading on it's [guide](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/how-to-get-started/). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have many options, but the most interesting one is to update recyclerView via EventBus (for example [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/):

Write this inside your app gradle file.

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
}
```

declare it inside your application (Use dagger2 to avoid static)

```
public static Bus bus = new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.MAIN);
```

then create a receiving method inside your activity(where recycler is declared)
and register it in Oncreate method of your activity:

```
@Subscribe
public void getMessage(String s) {
  adapter.addItem(s); // suppose adapter is recyclerAdapter
}

//requires a registration e.g. in the onCreate method
//bus is your static variable declared in Application class.
bus.register(this);
```

Then inside your onCreate method of Service call:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    bus.post("Hello");
}
```

Comment: So, with a library? How about without library?

Comment: use BroadCastReceiver, but this thing is complicated and requires more coding.

Comment: I can't make it work with this function. can you be more specific on how can i do this with the library?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Also, you can click the link I've provided and see the official documentation

Comment: I've updated my Question, Please check it out. I can't make it work.

Comment: I really don't get it on how to use otto.

Comment: try to read the documentation carefully. And look through this article : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-EventBusOtto/article.html

Answer (score 0):

This question is poorly phrased. What you are really asking is how you can communicate data from your service to your activity/fragment (presumably loading some IO intensive data or something), and then the activity/fragment can update the adapter and the UI accordingly.

There are plenty of other SO questions that answer this, for example:

[How to have Android Service communicate with Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463175/how-to-have-android-service-communicate-with-activity)

[Communication between Activity and Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594936/communication-between-activity-and-service)