# OnTouchEvent not working in service class

Tags: android

In my app I want to detect the swipes done by user by using `GestureEvent` method with `OnTouchEvent` method.The `OnTouchEvent` works only in activity class when I try to implement it in service class it doesn't implement.How to implement onTouchEvent in service class. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible. You should handle the GestureEvent in the activity and implement some sort of communication between your activity and the service.

This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29101448/2442831

Comment: but then how OmniSwipe or LazySwipe like apps work .

Comment: these are widgets https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html