# RemoteException in IntentService

Tags: java, android, android-service, remoteexception

I have the following code in my `IntentService` to send a `Message` to the registered clients:

```
for(Messenger client : clients) {
    client.send(aMessage);
}
```

According to the documentation of `send()`, this method can throw a `RemoteException`, a `DeadObjectException` specifically.

From the documentation of `DeadObjectException`:

> The object you are calling has died, because its hosting process no
>   longer exists.

If i understand correctly, this means that if my clients are all from the `Service`'s process, (theoretically) this `Exception` will **never** be thrown.

Am i correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: will also occur regardless of same process if the service itself stopped but the process is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**
But important to note that the whole purpose of `Messenger` is to communicate with different processes as mentioned in the official documentation:

> If you need your service to communicate with remote processes, then you can use a Messenger.

If you need to communicate with your service in the same process I would recommend using [local bound service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As i understand using Messenger is required if i would like to implement two-way communication. Without using a Messenger i can call methods of my Service, but i cannot call methods of my Activity from the Service. Am i wrong?

Comment: You're right again, if you need two way communication you can either use messenger, or (depends on your needs)  use binder to communicate with your service and localBroadcastReceiver to notify your activity about new info, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20595215/6028746