# Communicating with a Service Thread

Tags: android

I need help with something fairly basic I am having trouble understanding after a few hours of research and reading.

I have:

```
Service
   -Thread
       Method: write(string)
```

I need to pass a variable string from MainActivity to service and call write(string) when string changes.  I started to implement a broadcast receiver in the main service but how do I call write(string) method from the main service?  Do I need to put the receiver in the thread instead?  I'm having a hard time understanding what I'm doing here.  Please let me know if there is a better way.

The service contains all the Bluetooth connection and send/receive code.  I plan in the future to have another service send data to the Bluetooth service to send to the BT device.

Answer (score 0):

I am still a beginner at Android too but I think what you are looking for are [Bound Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html). There is also a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594936/communication-between-activity-and-service).