# Activity B notify a Activity A after calling finish()

Tags: java, android

I start Activity B from Activity A. Activity B does something to my Data and at some point I call `finish();`, however Activity B is still doing something with my Database in the background and when its finished I want to get notified in Activity A, that this process is finished.

Because there is no way to my knowledge to call a method from another activity I tried to solve this problem with `startActivityForResult` but because Im calling `finish();` before actually setting a Result this does not seem to work either.

Any Idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: This use case is a little bit weird. Could you explain more about this use case and why you need to do some background process started in activity B but notified in activity A?

Comment: Certainly there are tips and tricks that will do what you are asking, but I suspect your UX scenario is not well executed. What long process could you be doing in activity B that needs to inform activity A?

Comment: Well im using a realtime database (Firebase) and in Activity A I display an Object and in Activity B I can modify it and update it on the Database. After finishing I wanted to finish the Activity and let the updating process be done in the background. Once this is finished the Activity A should be notified, that there is new Data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do task in `Activity` that may live beyond `Activity` lifecycle. In that case do your task in `Service` and notify the Result to `Activity`. There are some ways to communicate between `Activity` and `Service` using [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver) , [Messenger](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger), [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler), [Bound Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services) . You can also use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library for this  communication.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594936/communication-between-activity-and-service) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging) thread for communicating between Activity and Service

Answer (score 0):

Try to close your database, and after it's been closed successfully, 'notify' your activity A about this result and finish activity. Quite an imprecise question, frankly :P 
And if you want to invoke some method from another class, pass the activity's Context.