# Passing Data from a Service to an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, service, broadcast

I build an Android app where my mobile device connects with a bluetooth device. I have a service where the connection is established and four values that I get from my ble device(temperature, light battery and state). My goal is to to send the values every time they are received. In the onCharacteristicChanged method the values are received and I want to send them to  DeviceControlActivity and display them in text views. How is it possible to achieve that? Thanks in advance.

BluetoothLeService:

```
package com.example.drodo.diamondbeacons;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.VibrationEffect;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {
    private final static String TAG = BluetoothLeService.class.getSimpleName();

    private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private String mBluetoothDeviceAddress;
    private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
    private int mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;

    private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 2;

    public final static String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
    public final static String ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED";
    public final static String ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED";
    public final static String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
    public final static String EXTRA_DATA =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA";

    // Implements callback methods for GATT events that the app cares about.  For example,
    // connection change and services discovered.
    private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            String intentAction;
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
                // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
                Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                        mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
                setPuckCharacteristicNotification();
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onCharacteristicRead");
                //broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            //Log.i(TAG, "onCharacteristicChanged");
            byte[] dataBytes = characteristic.getValue();
            String puckData = null;

            try {

                puckData = new String(dataBytes, "UTF-8");
                puckData = puckData.replaceAll("[\u001Ba-zA-Z>\\[\\]\\s+]","");

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to convert message bytes to string");
            }

            assert puckData != null;

            final String[] data = puckData.split("-");

            Log.e("D@T@-->", "LIGHT: " + data[0] + "%" + " " + "TEMP: " + data[1] + "\u2103" + " " + "BATTERY: " + data[2]
                    + " " + "ALERT: " + data[3]);

            double light = Double.parseDouble(data[0]);
            int temperature = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
            double battery = Double.parseDouble(data[2]);
            int myState = Integer.parseInt(data[3]);

            //broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
            if (battery <= 2.7) {
                try {

                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                            .setContentTitle("Puck.js Device - Replace the Battery")
                            .setContentText("Battery Level: " + battery + " V")
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),R.drawable.icons8_charged_battery_96))
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            //.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC); //to show content in lock screen

                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

                    PowerManager.WakeLock screenLock = ((PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE)).newWakeLock(
                            PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
                    screenLock.acquire(10000);

                    //later
                    screenLock.release();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCharacteristicWrite");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onDescriptorWrite");


            BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(PuckConstants.PUCK_SERVICE_UUID);
            if (service != null) {
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic =
                        service.getCharacteristic(PuckConstants.PUCK_TX_UUID);
                if (characteristic != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Writing to characteristic  " + characteristic.getUuid());

                    //String msg = "getMy()\n";

                    //byte[] data = msg.getBytes();

                    //characteristic.setValue(data);
                    if (gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic)) {
                        characteristic.getValue();
                        Log.i(TAG, "writeCharacteristic OK");
                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "writeCharacteristic FAIL");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }



    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        BluetoothLeService getService() {
            return BluetoothLeService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        // After using a given device, you should make sure that BluetoothGatt.close() is called
        // such that resources are cleaned up properly.  In this particular example, close() is
        // invoked when the UI is disconnected from the Service.
        close();
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    /**
     * Initializes a reference to the local Bluetooth adapter.
     *
     * @return Return true if the initialization is successful.
     */
    public boolean initialize() {
        if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
            mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize BluetoothManager.");
                return false;
            }
        }

        mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to obtain a BluetoothAdapter.");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }


    public boolean connect(final String address) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
            return false;
        }

        // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
        if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
                && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
            if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        if (device == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
            return false;
        }
        // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
        // parameter to false.
        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
        Log.i(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
        mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
        mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
        return true;
    }


    public void disconnect() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
    }


    public void close() {
        if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.close();
        mBluetoothGatt = null;
    }


    public void readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
    }

    /**
     * Enables notification on a given characteristic.
     **/
    public void setPuckCharacteristicNotification() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }

        //Start getting data
        BluetoothGattService gattService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(PuckConstants.PUCK_SERVICE_UUID);
        if (gattService != null) {
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic = gattService.getCharacteristic(PuckConstants.PUCK_RX_UUID);
            if (gattCharacteristic != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Setting Characteristic " + gattCharacteristic.getUuid());
                mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(gattCharacteristic, true);
                BluetoothGattDescriptor clientDescriptor = gattCharacteristic.getDescriptor(PuckConstants.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG);
                clientDescriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(clientDescriptor);
            }
        }
    }


    public List<BluetoothGattService> getSupportedGattServices() {
        if (mBluetoothGatt == null) return null;

        return mBluetoothGatt.getServices();
    }
}
```

DeviceControlActivity:

```
package com.example.drodo.diamondbeacons;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DeviceControlActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final static String TAG = DeviceControlActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME = "DEVICE_NAME";
    public static final String EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "DEVICE_ADDRESS";

    private Toolbar bleToolbar;
    private TextView mConnectionState;
    private TextView mDataField;
    private Button mainBtn;
    private String mDeviceName;
    private String mDeviceAddress;
    private BluetoothLeService mBluetoothLeService;
    private boolean mConnected = false;

    // Code to manage Service lifecycle.
    private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
            mBluetoothLeService = ((BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
            if (!mBluetoothLeService.initialize()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth");
                finish();
            }
            // Automatically connects to the device upon successful start-up initialization.
            mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            mBluetoothLeService = null;
        }
    };

    private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                mConnected = true;
                mConnectionState.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                updateConnectionState(R.string.connected);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                mConnected = false;
                mConnectionState.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOrange));
                updateConnectionState(R.string.disconnected);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                clearUI();
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
                // Show all the supported services and characteristics on the user interface.
                //displayGattServices(mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices());

            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
                displayData(intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA));
            }
        }
    };

    private void clearUI() {
        mDataField.setText(R.string.no_data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gatt_services_characteristics);

        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        mDeviceName = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME);
        mDeviceAddress = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS);


        // Sets up UI references.
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.device_address)).setText(mDeviceAddress);
        mConnectionState = findViewById(R.id.connection_state);
        mDataField = findViewById(R.id.data_value);
        mainBtn = findViewById(R.id.main_btn);
        bleToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.ble_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(bleToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Ble Devices");
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BluetoothLeService.class);
        bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        mainBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mainActivity = new Intent(DeviceControlActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainActivity);
                //finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver, makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());
        if (mBluetoothLeService != null) {
            final boolean result = mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
            Log.d(TAG, "Connect request result=" + result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unbindService(mServiceConnection);
        mBluetoothLeService = null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gatt_services, menu);
        if (mConnected) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_connect).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_disconnect).setVisible(true);
        } else {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_connect).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_disconnect).setVisible(false);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_connect:
                mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_disconnect:
                mBluetoothLeService.disconnect();
                return true;
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void updateConnectionState(final int resourceId) {
        runOnUiThread(() -> mConnectionState.setText(resourceId));
    }

    private void displayData(String data) {
        if (data != null) {
            mDataField.setText(data);
        }
    }

    private static IntentFilter makeGattUpdateIntentFilter() {
        final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE);
        return intentFilter;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29101448/4657385

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communication between Activity and Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594936/communication-between-activity-and-service)

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use LocalBroadcast()  to send data from service to activity.

Comment: Could you please send me piece of code? I would be very thankful because I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Please see above Anmol is given.

Answer (score 0):

Use the broadcast-receiver for the service-activity communication.

When you want to send the data back to the activity, at the end of onCharacteristicChanged method, send the broadcast as below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("IntentFilterSendData");
intent.putExtra("tempKey", temperature);
intent.putExtra("lightKey", light);
intent.putExtra("batteryKey", battery);
intent.putExtra("stateKey", myState);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And you can receive the data in activity by

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Double temperature = intent.getDoubleExtra("tempKey", 20);
    Double light = intent.getDoubleExtra("lightKey", 0);
    Double battery = intent.getDoubleExtra("batteryKey", 0);
    Double state = intent.getDoubleExtra("batteryKey", 0);
    //Use the data
}
```

};

and register the receiver dynamically in onResume by:

```
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("IntentFilterSendData"));
```

and unregister it in onPause by:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver);
```

Comment: onResume and onPause in my Activity??

Comment: onResume() and onPause() are the lifecycle methods of the activity. Register the broadcast receiver in onResume and unregister in onPause.