# Working with broadcast receiver and services. / android

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I am writing here after countless hours searching the net with no gain.

I am trying to create an app which starts a service, this service will have a broadcast receiver in him which should detect when a phone call is received, than this receiver calls a method inside the service with the calling number.

Can anyone help me out here? what should i be looking for? in short how should i handle this?

Comment: The reason you haven't found anything after hours of seeking is that you just don't know what to seek for. My advice is to buy yourself a nice book on Android and study it carefully before you develop any software on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463175/how-to-have-android-service-communicate-with-activity#answer-4739898)  Sounds like for you, you might simply use a singlton instance of your service, or perhaps a broadcast receiver.  Definitely stay away from AIDL.