# How or why can't I access an Activity's attribute from a Service?

Tags: java, android, service

This might be a silly question, but I don't get why a Service cannot access an Activity when it is instantiated/running. I have a static attribute (actually a HashMap) in my Activity, so I needed to access its content and copy to my Service (then be independent to run on the background).
Whenever I try to access a class from my Service I get a NullPointer.

My code is basically this.
Within the Activity:

```
// check if its static attribute is empty
startService(new Intent(MyService.class.getName()));
```

Within MyService (which extends Service):

```
serviceList = MainActivity.list; // Here I suppose I should clone my list
```

I just didn't want to maybe send it through Parcel or Serialization, because I have custom objects in this HashMap.

Any solutions/explanation?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463175/how-to-have-android-service-communicate-with-activity

Comment: Yes, I checked this topic before. But it's a different scenario and the answers are exactly what I am avoiding (since I am passing custom Objects, not just messages or events)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I had my service running in a different process, so whenever I tried to access anything in my Activity, I got a NullPointerException.

Hope it helps someone in the future!