# How to create an interface to interact with service methods from activity

Tags: android

I want to create an interface which will interact with an already running Service from the Activity in foreground.
viz, if there is a service called  **MyService**  running in background and I want to use the methods defined in the service from an activity called  **MyActivity** then how will I do it.

Comment: There are lots of interface example out there for **Java** search it and you would get an idea.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities for an activity to communicate with a service and vice versa.

1. LocalBroadcast receiver that is provided by Android framework , v4 support library also provided.
2. AIDL for services in a different process
3. Handler and ResultReceiver or Messenger

To get details implementation visit following links :
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0):

[You need to make your service bindable.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) or more specifically something like this [LocalService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LocalService.java) taken from the android guide.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are pretty apt ....but if you are bent on interfaces then... below is how one can do using interfaces ...but a better and more preferred way is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2463746/2079692)

Create a `Interface` with a function as below:

```
public interface OnChangeListener {

    void onChange();
}
```

then in your service :

```
private OnChangeListener changeListener;


public void setChangeListener(OnChangeListener changeListener) {
    this.changeListener = changeListener;
}
```

Some where in your service :

```
changeListener.onChange();
```

then from your Activity do this :

```
MyService.getInstance(this)
                    .setChangeListener(new OnChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChange() {
                            // do something here
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: can we **getInstance** from every activity of the application

Comment: yes from every activity ..It is a static function to maintain only one instance, Though this is not  right approach to use services.

Comment: i already created a static method like **getInstance** in the service but it works only in the activity in which the service starts and returns null for every other activity. My static concepts are not very clear :p

Comment: can u tell me how to get the service instance from every activity of the app

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do ?