# Use broadcasts or direct reference for background service

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, background-service

I'm working on a Bluetooth background service for android. Is there a preferred way of communicating with such a service in Android? I can either obtain a reference to the service directly, or communicate via broadcastrecievers. If there is a 3rd way to do it, I'd be happy to look into that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think both ways are good. And a 3rd way is using AIDL which I think is not that easy. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2463746/3265888

AIDL is basically android style IPC.

Comment: This won't be any good since it's running in the same process as the app. Thanks though :)