# Updating Activity's ArrayAdapter from a Service

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I am new to Android development, and have followed a [tutorial](http://mcuhq.com/27/simple-android-bluetooth-application-with-arduino-example) to set up a Bluetooth activity for my mobile application.  I got the code from the tutorial working, but then needed to move my Bluetooth code over to a Service.  In the process of moving the code over, I am having trouble handling when the code updates an ArrayAdapter.

```
//BluetoothService.java
public void discover(View view){
    //Check if the device is already discovering
    if(bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Discovery stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        if(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Discovery started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is not on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            // Add the name to the list
            String deviceName = device.getName();
            bluetoothArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            bluetoothArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
};
```

In the `BroadcastReceiver`, `bluetoothArrayAdapter` is not defined, as it is defined in the activity.  The activity simply calls the `discover` function:

```
//BluetoothActivity.java
private void discover(View view){
    bluetoothArrayAdapter.clear(); //Clear items
    bluetoothService.discover(view);
}
```

Being new to Android and Java, I'm not how I should go about updating the ArrayAdapter.  Should I be creating an array to return to the activity, which is then used to update the `bluetoothArrayAdapter`?

Comment: You should check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463175/how-to-have-android-service-communicate-with-activity) with many options of how to achieve communication between service and activity

Comment: @Gustavo based on what I'm seeing from that post, should I have moved my `BroadcastReceiver` to my Service?  Or should it have stayed in the Activity?

Comment: You can achieve this in several way . First Make Service as Bounded . Second Set a callback to Service . Third you can use Local Broadcast or `EventBus`  to notify Activity . If Service only serves the Activity the go with first option make it Bounded .